# Writing to USB HID Device with IOKit IOHIDDeviceSetReportWithCallback

Tags: macos, asynchronous, usb, hid, iokit

I am trying to communicate asynchronously with a USB HID Device using the IOHIDManager from IOKit. I have no problem registering for a callback with `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputReportCallback` and setting reports with `IOHIDDeviceSetReport`. But when I try and use `IOHIDDeviceSetReportWithCallback` to communicate with the device it's a no go.

Error is kIOReturnUnsupported (0xE00002C7).

Here is a link to a gentleman with the same issue from the apple usb mailing list.

http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2009/Oct/msg00004.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't want to think that this [response](http://lists.apple.com/archives/usb/2009/Oct/msg00005.html) to the above message was correct, but I can confirm that, this method is not implemented. Here is part of the response from Apple Developer Technical Support:

> Looking thru the sources IOHIDDeviceSetReportWithCallback just calls
>   (*device->deviceInterface)->setReport; in theory that should be the
>   IOKIT HID driver… looking at that it just returns
>   kIOReturnUnsupported…

Comment: Thank you for saving me the trouble of wasting more hours on that one!